# How to get itemSize for VariableSizeList in react-window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-window

The reason why I want to use react-window is to avoid excessive DOM problem. Also, because I'm using `nextjs` and `React.lazy()` doesn't work there. I have a `Layout` component in which the children are being dynamically generated, you can see the problem being solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593473/how-to-get-element-height-and-width-from-reactnode). However, it seems to me that it's not possible to get the height of the children beforehand.

In addition to the `LayoutWrapper` as shown in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593473/how-to-get-element-height-and-width-from-reactnode), the `VariableSizeList` is being setup for me as follow:

```
const [heights, setHeights] = React.useState<number[]>([])

React.useEffect(() => {
  // This will actually returns [] which I don't want to happen.
  // I want it to return an array of heights
  const data = onMount()
  setHeights(data)
}, [onMount])

const Row = ({index, style}: ListChildComponentProps) => (
  <div style={style}>{childrenArr[index]}</div>
)

const getItemSize = (index: number) => heights[index]

return (
   <AutoSizer disableWidth>
     {({height, width}) => (
       <VariableSizeList
         height={height}
         itemCount={childrenArr.length}
         itemSize={getItemSize}
         width={width}
       >
        {Row}
       </VariableSizeList>
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
)
```

Is there any work around solution to this?